# Adhesive light mount

Tags: commuter

I would like to attach a rear light to a hard plastic carrier on the back of my bike. No place to hook or tie. Is there an adhesive mount available to attach the light to?

Answer (score 4):

The common solution is to use a seat-post mounted rear light, with some kind of rubber-band that secures the light to the seatpost.  However your mention of hard plastic carrier suggests there's a box in the way.

Products like 3M Ultra high bond double-sided tape can be used to stick all sorts of things together.

Black plastic zip ties can work well too - the white ones go brittle over time in UV but black ones last longer.

Downside is that it can be difficult to change batteries or to take a light inside for charging.

I've 3D printed lamp holders for specific bikes, and they work well enough but are not at all generic.   Creativity will help a lot.  Good luck!

---

A lateral solution is to also attach the rear light to your helmet - some brands even have a red rear light option for the helmet.  This should be above your carrier.

Lastly, you might need to look at vehicle/trailer rear lamps and permanently attach it to the box, and wire to a battery.

Comment: What about attaching the lamp to a seatstay, or even one to each of the stays?

Comment: @Carel yep that would work.   Potentially they're getting a little low to the ground and could be obscured more/sooner in the dark.  I'd go with the helmet light as well to balance it all out.  That said - my bents each have one rear light attached to the offside chainstay, which is only 13" off the road.